# Human Tracking using KLT and mean shift

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm trying to track humans at a farther distance from a camera. I'm stuck between two algorithms here. KLT and Mean shift tracker.

Is it possible to use a mean shift tracker whose initialization is done by the KLT tracker (ie the mean shift tracker needs to be initialized and those initial feature points be provided by the results of applying KLT on the image sequence. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the initialization of detection on the first frame?

Comment: Yes. If KLT initialization is possible in this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KLT isn't an object tracking algorithm. KLT will only estimate the displacement of a keypoint between frame at time **t** with the frame at time **t-1**.

On the other hand, Mean-sift tracking is better suited for tracking objects, altho it's not very robust nor precise. You can watch an example of [Mean-Shift here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_meanshift/py_meanshift.html).

If you need to track object, and be safe to possibile probems like occlusion, scale changes, appearance changes you need to adpot a real tracking algorithm. There are many of them you can watch an example of a tracking algorithm using keypoints here: [Matrioska: Real-time Tracking using Keypoints](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVWyZse9z4E)